# Change timestamp with touch in Android

Tags: android, adb, busybox

I'm trying to change the timestamp of the pictures I copied to my new phone from my old one. I'm using busybox's touch command through adb shell. The files names are like: IMG_20131203_223152.jpg so:

```
# for i in `ls IMG_*` ; 
do 
    d=`echo $i|cut -d"_" -f2` ; 
    t=`echo $i|cut -d"_" -f3|cut -d"." -f1` ; 
    touch -t $d.$t $i ; 
done
```

It requieres to be root in order to change the timestamp but it works, as I can see with and "ls -l". The problem is that if I go to Pictures on the phone and see the Details still show the timestamp of the moment I copied the pictures from the computer. It`s like the changes are not persisted. Ejecting and unpluging the phone from the computer doesn't work either. And I forgeting something? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My phone hasn't external sdcard so I think is emulated using FUSE.

Comment: pictures information are into the exif. Change the last modified access of the file does not change what's written in the exif

Comment: Just a little note for those who found this, but the touch command didn't change anything even though they were root. Earlier, I've copied some backed up photos to the phone under recovery. That had the tiny consequence that those files were owned by root:root. This is to be seen only from recovery. The FUSEd filesystem on android shows same owner as all the other sdcard files, but touch won't do anything. The trick is to go back to recovery and chown the uploaded files to media_rw:media_rw. Killed a few hours on this, I hope you won't have to.

Comment: Can I copy the previously mentioned bash code directly into an adb shell terminal, or do I have to make a script.sh first?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was pretty stupid, I just have to reboot the phone.

Comment: Clearing data of the gallery ("Pictures")  app should be enough.